# .Htaccess redirect url if visited from android

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I try to redirect all users that visit my site from Android phone to  example.com/ANDROID and I try the following.

This is my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^v=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^watch$ /#/watch/%1? [L,NE,R]

Options -Indexes

AddType application/octet-stream .m4a
AddType application/octet-stream .aac
```

I try to add

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android" [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /ANDROID/$1 [L,QSA]
```

after `RewriteEngine On`, but the problem is I get internal server error 500.

Comment: I was not able to reproduce the error 500. The only i think that you need to remove the double quotes around the android

Comment: error is shown when i visit site from android

Comment: This question does not contain enough information to properly answer. Internal Server errors log something in your Apache error log. Open that log, find the line that corresponds to your 500 internal server error and [edit] your question with this information with the link under your question. Then leave a comment so I get notified.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^v=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^watch$ /#/watch/%1? [L,NE,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/ANDROID/.*$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|iemobile|operamobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /ANDROID/ [L,R=302]
```